# Injecting ApplicationScoped bean into Web Filter results in null object

Tags: cdi, servlet-filters

I have the following ApplicationScoped bean

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;   
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserService implements Serializable {...
```

And I am trying to inject it into a web filter

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
@WebFilter("/admin/*")
public class AdminFilter implements Filter{

@Inject
private UserService userService;
```

The injected userService is null in the doFilter method. I can't figure out what I am missing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what server and version of the server are you running this application? Does injection work in other places?

Comment: I'm running tomcat 9.0 and injection works in all other places. Just not this filter.

Comment: If its null that means CDI has not processed your class. I would check the obvious possibilities like making sure your beans.xml doesn't veto the class. I also log out a stack from the filter's constructor and make sure tomcat is creating the object and not something in your code creating it in a way CDI cannot see. It helps more often that you might expect.